# ajax request sometime fails due to ERR_CONNECTION_RESET but not always

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am submitting a form using ajax. Form is consist of some textboxes, textareas etc (string data) and a file as well. I am sending the form as javascript `FormData()`.

The problem is that the Ajax request sometimes failed but not always.
e.g. I tried to upload bigger files in zip, it was uploaded successfully five times but on the sixth attempt it got failed due to an error i got in the console **"ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"**

How to overcome this that it never happens. Thanks

Ajax Request using FormData():

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("consider all my data here from form",data);
$.ajax({
                url : 'abc.com/controller/function&token='+token,
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loader").show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loader").hide();
                },
                success: function(json){
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    console.log(json);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Something went wrong while updating chapter info. Please, refresh and try again.");
                }

            });
```

Comment: Is there a maximum file size set on the server? For example, in PHP language you can set post_max_size or upload_max_filesize.

Comment: max_execution_time = 4600 , upload_max_filesize = 50M , 
max_file_uploads = 50 , memory_limit = 8048M   . All these are fine regarding that uploading. PLease, keep in mind that it does uploaded but sometimes it is failed and i tried to debug which gave me that error.

Comment: Have you looked at the php and apache/IIS error logs?